# how to keep a "permanent" clip in Ditto

Tags: clipboard, ditto

I am using Ditto for quite a while now and it is a great little clipboard manager. A while ago, I have managed to set one of the clips (a copy item in Ditto) as a "permanent" one. Meaning, when I open up the main console of Ditto in order to access all the copied items, this one will always appear first.
I don't remember how I did that back then and now I want to do it for other items. Does anyone know how to do this? I haven't been able to find any documentation or help about this specific issue.

This is the icon that appears next to the permanent item:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answer: In Ditto, this is called a Sticky Clip. Sticky Clips always show at the top of the history list before any other clips.

To make a clip sticky:

- Right-click > Clip Order > Make Top Sticky Clip
- Right-click > Clip Order > Make Last Sticky Clip

To move a sticky clip up or down without making it the top or bottom sticky (these commands also work for non-sticky clips):

- Right-click > Clip Order > Move Up
- Right-click > Clip Order > Move Down

To remove the sticky setting:

- Right-click > Clip Order > Remove Sticky Setting

To move a non-sticky clip to the top of the list of non-sticky clips (this command *only* works for *non-sticky* clips):

- Right-click > Clip Order > Move To Top

Good question! The Ditto help and FAQ do not reflect the awesome things the developer and the community have done to improve the software. I hope this helps you. I love sticky clips. I use it as a poor woman's text expander, because the sticky clips correspond to the quick paste hot keys.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone wondering how to keep a permanent clip, but NOT have it pinned on top of the other entries, what you can do is flag it with "Never Auto Delete":

[image]

In such way, it will be always available and never deleted if you have tons of newer clips.

You will still need to have to search for it (writing a part of it), but you won't clutter your window with sticky clips.

For me it is very useful e.g. for storing semi-frequent commands and code snippets, but I don't want them visible all the time.